# Why the scope prototype is not working for the spring bean which implements BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, scope

I have a **Bean** which `implements` `BeanPostProcessor`

```
public class ScopeTest implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public ScopeTest() {
        System.out.println("ScopeTest()");
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessBeforeInitialization()");
        return null;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessAfterInitialization()");
        return null;
    }
}
```

and I have configured it in Spring bean configuration file with `scope` as `prototype`.

```
<bean id="st" class="com.test.ScopeTest" scope="prototype" />
```

and I run the code using `ApplicationContext`

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext container = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    }
}
```

and the output I observed is

```
ScopeTest()
```

Here what makes the container to create the object for the bean which is marked as `prototype` without `getBean()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype scope does not work here because BeanPostProcessor implementations are discovered, instantiated and registered only on Spring application context startup. These beans get sorted by type (before/after instantiation etc.) and are stored in lists. From there, PostProcessor beans are applied on further bean creations. Compared to "ordinary" beans (like service beans) they're not retrieved from the context a second time after startup. So the scope they're applied to is not considered.

Comment: I found these lines from Spring Reference.  **An ApplicationContext automatically detects any beans that are defined in the configuration metadata which implement the BeanPostProcessor interface.**